# XmlPullParser is not working with InputStream

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am using XmlPullParser for xml parsing in my android app but when I set input as InputStream it not works while I set input as Reader it starts working

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(obj,null);//obj is the object of InputStream
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                 logger.println("eventType.."+eventType);
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                     // control goes here only

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                  //This block never executed
                  }

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                 //This block never executed
              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

              }
              eventType = xpp.next();
             }
```

Even if I store data from InputStream object in a string and set that String as input then this code also works fine.

```
xpp.setInput(new StringReader(str));//str contains the data from InputStream
```

Comment: what does the xml declaration (i.e. the "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`" part) in your document look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<res_transfer ip="" uuid="" type="2" cons_tf_id="" prod_tf_id="">
 <file_data type="0" name="" chunkno="" totalchunks="" md5="" bytes="" /> 
</res_transfer>   this is my xml structure

Comment: Can you post the code where you create `obj`?

Comment: InputStram obj=socket.getInputStream();

Comment: Do you perform any action in the loop (apart from checking the eventType)? Maybe it is related to the namespace awareness, try to remove the line `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);` and see if that helps...

Comment: I already tried but it not worked

Answer (score 4):

The same problem: passing InputStream directly works fine on Android 2.3.3 but doesn't work on 4.1.
You can use `xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(obj));`

Comment: Running Android 4.3 and InputStreamReader generates the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for a similar problem from yano on this thread: [XmlPullParser - unexpected token (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438491/xmlpullparser-unexpected-token-android?rq=1)

You need to move from file from res/xml to assets and get the file with the code:

```
InputStream in = this.getAssets().open("sample.xml");
```

Apparently getRawResource() does not read the encoding properly and if you just dump the contents of the inputstream there are plenty of garbage characters.